# Count number os specific strings in Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I count the numbers of a specific string in a pandas column  ?
I want to get its percentage with respect to the total number of strings in the pandas column.

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Ho please, gives more context, what input you have, what output you want and add relevant part of your code in your question

Comment: Are you looking for `df['col'].value_counts() / len(df) * 100`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need for check string `a` compare and `mean` of boolean mask:

```
print (df['col'].eq('a').mean())
#same as
#print ((df['col'] == 'a').mean())
```

And for all values [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
print (df['col'].value_counts(normalize=True))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':list('aaabbc')})
print (df)
  col
0   a
1   a
2   a
3   b
4   b
5   c

print (df['col'].eq('a').mean())
0.5

print (df['col'].value_counts(normalize=True))
a    0.500000
b    0.333333
c    0.166667
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

If `None`s in column `value_count`s function drop it first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a','a','a','b','b','c',None]})
print (df)
    col
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
5     c
6  None

print (df['col'].eq('a').mean())
0.428571428571

#first drop NaN/Nones and then normalize
print (df['col'].value_counts(normalize=True))
a    0.500000
b    0.333333
c    0.166667
Name: col, dtype: float64

#convert None/None to string for count it
print (df['col'].astype(str).value_counts(normalize=True))
a       0.428571
b       0.285714
None    0.142857
c       0.142857
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works for all my strings, except for the string "None". Do you know why ?

Comment: I think for `NaN`s and `None`s need `df['col'].isnull().mean()`, because `np.nan != np.nan`, it is gotcha in pandas/numpy

Comment: I do some tests and answer was edited, if use `value_count`s with `None/NaN`s.